# How to create multilingual URLs in vuejs with WPML and GraphQL?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, vuejs3, wpml, headless-cms

How can I get/create urls in vuejs with WPML and GraphQL. I have to change URL based on language code after click on language flag. There is @onclick="getLangCode(language.code)" on the flag.

```
const getLangCode = async (lang_code) => {
    await $axios.post('/', {query: "query GetDefaultLanguage { defaultLanguage { code } }" }).then(response => {
        const default_language_code = response.data.data.defaultLanguage.code
        const base_url = window.location.origin
        let param_lang = lang_code
        const param_slug = window.location.pathname;
        const regex = new RegExp(`^\\/${param_lang}\\/`);
        const cleaned_slug = param_slug.replace(regex, '/');
        if (param_lang === default_language_code) {
            param_lang = "";
        }else {
            param_lang = '/'+lang_code
        }
        window.location.replace(base_url+param_lang+cleaned_slug)
    })
    setLanguageCode(lang_code)
}
```

This code doesn't work correctly. Is any way how to create correct or get multilingual urls?